# How to postpone [permission request alert]?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

My app requires these permissions

- Notifications
- GPS
- Photos

the photos permission is requested when the user opens the gallery, but the first two permissions show app with the app launch, it's okay for me to have the GPS as the first permission to ask for, **but I want to postpone the notifications dialogue into another screen, how to do this?**

this [library](https://github.com/delba/Permission) seem to not allow this
any suggestions?

```
let notificationTypes : UIUserNotificationType = [UIUserNotificationType.Alert,UIUserNotificationType.Badge,UIUserNotificationType.Sound]
let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: notificationTypes, categories: nil)

application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
application.registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)
```

Comment: 1. You register notifications in AppDelegate, So it will definitely ask permission on Launch.

Comment: 2. For GPS, It will ask for that permission when you are trying to get location. If you are getting location in consider 2nd controller, Then it can be done, But if you are getting location in AppDelegate, I am afraid it will ask on app launch.

Comment: Try creating a method in AppDelegate. And Call that method When you want to show permission alert

Comment: you can separately ask for permission using ForRemoteNotifications code above in view controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks, this solves it for me,...

calling from app delegate

```
    let notificationTypes : UIUserNotificationType = [UIUserNotificationType.Alert,UIUserNotificationType.Badge,UIUserNotificationType.Sound]
    let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: notificationTypes, categories: nil)
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)
```

calling from another class

```
    let notificationTypes : UIUserNotificationType = [UIUserNotificationType.Alert,UIUserNotificationType.Badge,UIUserNotificationType.Sound]
    let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: notificationTypes, categories: nil)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)
```